# Design a portable JAVA code with swing using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to write a java code with GUI that is portable.(i.e. IDE independent). Using Netbeans I can design a form with its palette but if I copy the generated code into a blank file and try to compile it using `javac` in a shell, and try to run with `java` it produces an error. Here is a screen of shell (Windows cmd) and my java code:

```
public class test extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   public test() {
    initComponents();
}



private void initComponents() {

    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollBar1 = new javax.swing.JScrollBar();

   setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("test");

     jButton3.setText("Cancel");

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(160, 160, 160)
            .add(jButton3)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 161, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jScrollBar1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .add(91, 91, 91))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(142, 142, 142)
                    .add(jButton3))
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(28, 28, 28)
                    .add(jScrollBar1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 192, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(154, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack(); 
}                       

public static void main(String args[]) {



    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new test().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JScrollBar jScrollBar1;
}
```

And here is the error I got when running the program:

[image: Error]

Comment: It's portable, just include with it the appropriate jar file within the application's classpath. Or code your Swing GUI by hand using the tutorials.

Comment: [Other similar questions](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+exception+noclassdeffounderror+grouplayout$group)

Comment: If you want to be IDE independent, you might consider having a look at Maven, which most IDE's recognize. You should also avoid using form editors as they tend to be IDE dependent

Comment: The `swing-layout*.jar` is a dependency from Netbeans - again, avoid form editors